# Hold texts on activity A while on activity B

Tags: android, jquery, eclipse, text, edit

So i have 2 java files,
AddActivity,MapActivity.
I want to enter the details into the add activity and then  "Select Location" button,
Once "Select Location" button is selected the MapActivity starts, when i select the "Submit" button,
I am brought back to the AddActivity which should contain the previous details entered but it doesn't, any ideas?

```
private EditText edit_event,edit_time,edit_location,edit_date,edit_descript,edit_lat,edit_lon;
```

Select Location Button to move from AddActivity to MapActivity

```
            btn_locate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
          public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(AddActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }
            });
```

Submit Button to move from the MapActivity to AddActvity

```
    public void onClick_Submit(View v) {

    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), AddActivity.class);     
    newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(newIntent);

}
```

After i submit my previous text on add activity and went to map activity and went back to add activity the Edit texts disappeared, unfortunately i need 10 reps to post images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activities can pretty much be destroyed and recreated at any time. Therefore, if you want to cache information you have to do some extra work for this.

The easiest way is to use static variables on the activity, which will keep it stored for the lifetime of the application.

Another way is to use `SharedPreferences`, which will store information even when the application is terminated and restarted.

Yet another way is to use a local database with `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

When your activity come to the front, `OnStart()` is called. This is the place to reload the cached information.

When your activity goes to the background, `OnStop()` is called. This is the place to cache the information.

More information on the Activity Lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

More information on the Storage options in Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Hi, im doing some research with the sqlite helper and onstart() but not,many examples are out there, can you give me one or elaborate on this? Thx.

Comment: A lot of very helpful information is right there http://developer.android.com. For example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html